# Two auto generated IDs in Spring single entity

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, annotations, uuid, auto-generate

I need to generate two IDs (column values) in Spring with Annotations. 
What would be the solutions if I need 2 IDs auto generated with annotations, ID and UUID, I would use UUID generated with the following:

```
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
@Column(name = "uuid", unique = true)
private String uuid;
```

but I would not be able to use the @Id annotation at the same time and can not auto generate the ID (second generated field)

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
```

What would be the best solution to auto generate two columns ID and UUID, since with only one @Id only one is created and the other is null?
I need some solution with Hibernate, not programatically generating one of them.

Comment: You don't need the help of Hibernate or the database to generate a UUID. Why don't you do it yourself, programmatically? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html. Also, why do you need two different technical IDs in a single entity?

Comment: Even if the chance to have a same UUID twice is very unlikely it could happen, so I think it is the best solution to have Hibernate generate the both IDs.  I need two different IDs in a single entity because of the design. Do you know a solution to create the both IDs with Hibernate?

Comment: So, the UUID would check who tries to generate it, detect that it's Hibernate, and thus be extra careful not to generate a duplicate? If it's not Hibernate, it wouldn't care? "because of the design" is a tautology. Why did you choose to design it like this is the question. Did anyone point a gun to your head to force you doing that? What's the rationale behind that design choice?

Comment: Thanks @ JB Nizet  for the answers. I need two separate IDs not for extra check, but those are for completely different stuff  (one is not for check who tries to generate), :) it is not my design, so I wanted to search as an option if Hibernate can generate two different IDs in a single entity, apart of the option to generate them programmatically?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have temporary decided to use UUID.randomUUID(), but I am still eager to hear about other possible solutions for generating both ids through hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use custom query  like below

***@Modifying
@Query("insert into tablename values(some_val,some_val,(select max(some_id)+1 from sametablename))")
void saveEntity();***

it will run a subquery to fetch the latest value and increment by 1 and save it and you can omit autogenerated field and rely on jpa

EDIT : this query method is not thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

However another way I found is that we can use non-primary field for @Id annotation in JPA entity and provide @GeneratedValue annotation, it will work but it requires db sequence to be created in DB to generate the value and Primary field will be autogenerated by DB as it is